# assigning an int to a variable, from an arraylist value in another class

Tags: java, arraylist

Im very new to java and im in the process of making a student record system.

I'm currently stuck on trying to assign a previous stated integer (year the student is in) in an arraylist from a year class, to a new variable in a results class, so the user can input the result for the stated year the student is in.

here is my code

```
class StudentYear
{
    public void StudentYear()
    {             
        ArrayList<Integer> studentYear = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Please enter the year the student has most recently completed: ");
        studentYear.add(sc.nextInt());
        System.out.println(studentYear);
    }
}   

class Results
{
    public void Results()
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> results = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int year = // need to put arraylist value(0) from studentYear
        System.out.println("Please enter the results for "+year+":");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        results.add(sc.nextInt());
        System.out.println(results);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the get(int) function to retrieve values from lists:

```
int year = studentYear.get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

pass `studentYear` list to function

```
public void Results(List<Integer> studentYear )
{
    ArrayList<Integer> results = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int year = studentYear.get(0);
    //......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<Integer> StudentYear()
{             
    ArrayList<Integer> studentYear = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ...
    return studentYear;
}
public void Results(ArrayList<Integer> studentYear)
{
...
int year = studentYear.get(0);
...
}
```

To take a value out of a function, you have to return it. Then you can pass it in as a parameter to the second function.

Comment: getting an error with return, `cannot convert arraylist<integer> to int`
any work around for this?